# artifactory yum relative path not working

Tags: artifactory, yum

I have https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum configured as a remote repo in Artifactory.

My repo file on Centos 7.3 looks like this:

```
    [kubernetes]
    name=kubernetes
    baseurl=https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/packages.cloud.google.com-yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/
    enabled=1
    gpgcheck=1
```

When I run `yum install -y kubelet` it prints this error:

```
    e7a4403227dd24036f3b0615663a37 FAILED
    https://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/packages.cloud.google.com-yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/../../pool/e7a4403227dd24036f3b0615663a371c4e07a95be5fee53505e647fd8ae58aa6-kubernetes-cni-0.5.1-0.x86_64.rpm: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 500 - Internal Server Error
    Trying other mirror.
```

I am pretty sure the problem is the relative path in the URL: `kubernetes-el7-x86_64/../../pool`

If I wget the URL it works fine because wget is resolving out the relative path before sending the HTTP request, but yum does not do this and Artifactory returns a 500 when you give it a url with `../` in it. Does anyone know how to enable relative URLs in Artifactory? Or how to get yum to resolve URLs before sending the requests?

I am running these versions:

- Artifactory 5.2.0
- Yum 3.4.3-150

Update: This is the HTTP response body from artifactory:

```
    {
      "errors" : [ {
        "status" : 500,
        "message" : "Could not process download request: Path element cannot end with a dot: packages.cloud.google.com-yum-cache/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/../"
      } ]
    }
```

Comment: externally that url returns a 404 - is it only accessible from within gcloud?

Comment: https://artifactory.company.com is a censored URL. This server is only available within my company's network.

Answer (score 7):

The remote repository should be set with the following url in Artifactory
https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/

The baseurl on the yum client should point on the repodata folder with the following:
baseurl=http://artifactory.company.com/artifactory/yum-remote/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64/
(The name of the remote repository is 'yum remote')

This should work without any further configuration from the Artifactory side.

The error you have mentioned regardin the relative path 'kubernetes-el7-x86_64/../../pool' happens during the caching of the artifact.
Artifactory cannot cache to a path which contains the '..' pattern so the request is failing.
It can be solved from Artifactory side with a user plugin.
If the path contains the '..' pattern then the plugin will modify the path where the artifact will cached so it will not include this pattern.
This is now redundant as the registry retrieves paths which doesn't include '..' in them.

Comment: Is there an existing artifactory plugin that does the URL rewrite? What is the name?

Comment: You can find an example user plugin in the JIRA case's comment :
https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-9141